# MuleSoft Build Project Build Issues with Maven

Tags: maven, tfs, pom.xml, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I have to deploy MuleSoft Application on TFS with Maven But I am facing some issues because of some Enterprice library dependencies.
For theses Library I have to pass user name and password tp setting.xml file along with pom.xml file but i did not find the way to pass values to setting.xml file.

when i try to build my project on TFS i am facing below issue.

BUILD FAILURE

---

Total time: 51.360 s
 Finished at: 2017-04-17T10:50:39+00:00
 Final Memory: 10M/105M

---

Failed to execute goal on project demoproject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:demoproject:mule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core-ee:jar:3.8.3, com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-spring-config-ee:jar:3.8.3, org.mule.transports:mule-transport-file:jar:3.8.3, org.mule.transports:mule-transport-http:jar:3.8.3, com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports:mule-transport-jdbc-ee:jar:3.8.3, com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports:mule-transport-jms-ee:jar:3.8.3, org.mule.transports:mule-transport-vm:jar:3.8.3, org.mule.modules:mule-module-scripting:jar:3.8.3, org.mule.modules:mule-module-xml:jar:3.8.3, org.mule.tests:mule-tests-functional:jar:3.8.3, org.mule.modules:mule-module-http:jar:3.8.3, org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-config:jar:3.8.3: Could not find artifact com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core-ee:jar:3.8.3 in Central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) -> [Help 1]
To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
C:\java\maven\apache-maven-3.2.2\bin\mvn.bat failed with return code: 1
Could not retrieve code analysis results - Maven run failed.
Build failed.

Answer (score 0):

This Happen because you are using Entreprise Edition respository, In order to do this you have to add in your maven settings.xml some extra configurations :

```
<server>

    <id>MuleRepository</id>
    <username>YOUR_ID</username>
    <password>YOUR_PASSWORD</password>

</server>


<profile>

    <id>Mule</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>MuleRepository</id>
            <name>MuleRepository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</profile>
```

you could find more details here :

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb

Comment: But where to add Setting.xml file in project

Comment: I know this is because of Entreprise Edition respository but i didnot find the setting.xml file in the project.
it work properly on local anypoint and i have setting.xml file in .m2 folder in cdrive.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have installed Maven on TFS Build Agent, you just need to place the setting.xml file in the same path as your local machine.